# Creating DLL from asmx web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have created a web service as asmx which is running properly. Now I want the service binary in DLL format. How can I generate it?

Comment: Found solution on this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479568.aspx

Answer (score 2):

> How can I generate it?

You can't do that. The code behind of the service could be in a separate assembly but the `.asmx` file itself need to be part of an ASP.NET application which is hosting this service.

Comment: That's why I was wondering the compiled solution doesn't have any binaries with it, I heard about the "wdproj" which does but can't find any help!

Comment: No, a legacy WebService (.asmx) need to be hosted in an ASP.NET application. The new ASP.NET Web API on the other hand could be self hosted and you could create a self-contained binary.

Comment: @WaqarAlamgir, to encapsulate reusable .NET logic into it. `.asmx` is not exactly .NET code. It is the endpoint that need to be hosted in an ASP.NET application. But of course the entire code behind of your service could be placed in a reusable assembly. In the asmx you will then point to that assembly.